# PHP strtotime only converting correctly when adding days

Tags: php, strtotime

I am using strtotime in PHP, and getting two different result from the same input. I cannot work out why.

```
$startDate = 1468467219;
$oldDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($startDate));
$newDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+3 weekdays', $startDate));
```

The original date is `14/07/2016 01.33 PM`

`$newDate` is returning `19/07/2016` As expected.

`$oldDate` is returning `01/01/1970` Not the expected result - should be `14/07/2016`.

I have tried other functions inside strtotime and they all produce the correct result. What am I missing? Why can I not simply just pass `1468467219` to strtotime without modifying it?

Comment: `var_dump(strtotime($startDate));` = bool(false)

Comment: Interesting that it works when adding days then @Dagon

Comment: yup, im confused; hopefully someone smart will turn up

Comment: I'm using a work around `strtotime('+0 day', $startDate));`  which returns the result I needed. I am still curious about this functionality though. @Dagon

Comment: The first argument to `strtotime()` is a string containing a human-readable datetime. The second argument is a numeric timestamp. `strtotime($startDate)` doesn't work because `$startDate` is a timestamp, not a human-readable datetime.

Comment: Why do you need to call `strtotime()` when you already have a timestamp? Just use `date('d/m/Y', $startDate)`.

Comment: Doh! @Barmar thanks, my brain stops early on Friday afternoons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing `strtotime`.  This function takes a string representation of a date, and returns a timestamp.  Instead you're feeding it a timestamp

```
$startDate = 1468467219;
$oldDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($startDate));
```

Since no common date format is expressed as "today is 1468467219", the function is unable to parse it and returns false.

```
var_dump(strtotime($startDate)) //<-- boolean FALSE
```

When you go on to feed `FALSE` to the `date` function, it can't parse it either, so it returns the wrong date: `01/01/1970`.

To get the result you need just feed the timestamp directly to `date`:

```
$oldDate = date('d/m/Y', $startDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should only use:

```
$oldDate = date('d/m/Y', $startDate);
```

so, without `strtotime($startDate)`

When you are using `strtotime`, second parameter should be timestamp, but in your case it was the first one. But as first param should be one of Date and Time Formats.

Here more:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php